# Set Navbar Invisible on Button click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with my JavaScript code.

I have a navigation bar with 5 links on it. 
On default CSS settings, Navigation is fixed. But the thing I want to do is to change the navigation bar's position from fixed to sticky when someone click on one of those 5 links. But it looks like some part of my code doesn't work.

Here is the Code:

```
    var header = document.querySelector("header");
var isClicked = false;
var nav = document.querySelectorAll("a");

for(var i = 1; i < 6; i++){
    nav[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
        isClicked = true;
    });
}

if(isClicked === true){
    header.classList.remove("visible");
    header.classList.add("invisible");
}
```

I checked the console and when I click the links on the navigation bar, isClicked variable changes to true.
Looks like part of the code where I add and remove those classes doesn't get executed.

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Your `if` block will only be executed once. While `isClicked` callback function gets fired everytime the `click` event gets emitted. So you can't expect your header classList to change on every click. You can simply put the `if` block inside under `isClicked = true` though,

Comment: I think I understand what are you saying but header's class doesn't get changed even on first click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class removal or addition logic will be inside handler and also index should start from 0 otherwise first anchor will not add eventListener

```
var header = document.querySelector("header");
var nav = header.querySelectorAll("a");

for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    nav[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
        header.classList.remove("visible");
        header.classList.add("invisible");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this...

remove the .class and make it new as class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top"

*html*-

```
<input type="button" id="buttonChangeNav" value="make me Change!"/>
```

*JS* & *JQ*

```
buttonChangeNav.addEventListener("click",ChangeNav,true);

function ChangeNav(){
    header.removeAttr("class");
    header.setAttribute('class', navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top);
}
```

doc

https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/